# How to read list elements using Mootools

Tags: list, mootools

How to read each list elements using  Mootools in follows,

```
<ul id="TickerVertical">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <li>Fifth</li>
        <li>Sixth</li>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
        <li>Fifth</li>
        <li>Sixth</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "read"

```
var items = $('TickerVertical').getElements('li');
items.each(function(item, index){
  // item and index at your service
});
```

Comment: or you could use `var items = $$('#TickerVertical li');` for a bit better performance in modern browsers I believe.

Comment: or the cousins document.getElement and document.getElements to avoid the eye sore from the $ functions :) -- and yes, I think that the getElements/$$ version runs directly on QSA in Slick so it might be faster *if* the browser is faster at QSA than the pair of calls to gEBID and gEBTN.

Comment: @subhaze: not even close http://jsperf.com/mootools-selector-stuff, it's always fastest if you can get an element first, then search its decedents.

Comment: I thought with the new Slick engine it *would* grab that element then parse it as well as use the native `querySelectorAll` in any browser that provides it.